# I am making a user authentication page using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

The problem is that the query is not retrieving the correct value from the database rather it is not retrieving any value. Whenever I try to print the variable which holds the result, it is blank.
I am attaching a part of the code

This is the code in model

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=login;charset=utf8', 'root', 'learningit');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id FROM members WHERE userid='$username' AND password='$password'");  
    $stmt->execute();  
    $var=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach ((array)$var as $row) {
    print_r($row);
    return $row;
```

& this is the controller part

```
public function check()
    {

        $this->load->model('test_model');

        $result=$this->test_model->data_check();

        if($result[0]==1)
        {
          $this->call();
        }
        else if($result[0]==2)
        {
            $this->call1();
        }
        else if($result[0]==3)
        {
            $this->call2();
        }
        else
        {   
            echo "Invalid id/password";
        }   
    }
```

Comment: from where you get the variable `$username` and `$password`? put that code also.

Comment: use CI active records if you are using old style php mysql connection way its really bad please read Database documentation http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/index.html

Comment: I have declared $username & $password in the starting & taken values using the POST method @anantkumarsingh

Comment: Okay. Will read. Thanks @umefarooq

Comment: Message: mysql_pconnect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead

This is the wrror that i get when i dont use mysqli or PDO for database connection. @umefarooq

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing $username and $password declaration in your model

```
$username = $this->input->post('username'); // change this depends in your input 
$password = $this->input->post('password'); // change this depends in your input
```

Comment: Is it answer?If suggestion write it as comment.

Comment: I have declared them and taken values using the post method.